# Single table parent table with one junction table having many to many relationship is a good design?

Tags: database, many-to-many

Does the following design work with out any problems?
I want to create a junction table for the same table.
"ON DELETE CASCADE" should work too.

```
"source table (combining 
archive,object,sharedobject,source as a single table )" 

FileListTable
    ------------------------------- 
    id  file_type_id filename       license details
    1    1            A:/aa/bb/cc.c  xxx
    2    2            A:/aa/bb/aa.cpp   yyy
    3    2             A:/aa/bb/bb.cpp  zzz
    4    2             A:/aa/bb/cc.cpp  ttt
    5    6             A:/aa/bb/cc.so  abc
    6    5             A:/aa/bb/cc.a  axy
    7    7             A:/aa/bb/cc.o  ass
    8    8             A:/aa/bb/cc.o  ass
    -----------------------------------------
```

File type table with file extension ids.

```
file type table 
-------------------
file_type_id    file_ext
1                .c
2                .cpp
3                .h
4                .sh
5                .a
6                .so
7                 binary_with_no_ext
8                 .o
---------------------------------

filelist_junction_table
------------------
file_id_1 file_id_2
5        6
5        7
5        8


.. so on
----------------
```

Below is the query for above junction table.

```
CREATE TABLE `filelist_junction_table` (
  `file_id_1` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `file_id_2` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`file_id_1`,`file_id_2`),
  KEY `FK_file_id_idx` (`file_id_2`)
  CONSTRAINT `FK_file_id_1` FOREIGN KEY (`file_id_1`) REFERENCES `FileListTable` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_file_id_2` FOREIGN KEY (`file_id_2`) REFERENCES `FileListTable` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

Comment: It is worth trying first. Why do you think there should be a problem?

Comment: I want to associate relationship between files i.e a .so can be made by .so, .a, .o files. or .a is made by one or more .o's, this relationship I have created by junctiontable mentioned above."ON DELETE CASCADE" should work too.

Comment: So what exactly does not work?

Comment: @Bulat - I was seeking suggestion of whether is it good design?, OK will try to create it first and if any issues, will report.

Comment: It is an OK design. if you need to link files many-to-many, that is the only design for relational db.